# Diferença entre $.ajax(), $.get() e $.load()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Qual é a diferença entre `$.ajax()`, `$.get()` e `$.load()`?

Qual é o melhor para usar e em quais condições?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`$.ajax()`** Serve para fazer requisições assíncronas com qualquer método HTTP, entre eles o GET

**`$.get()`** É igual ao anterior porém só serve para requisições do tipo GET

A diferença entre os dois acima é que na primeira terá que passar um parâmetro adicional

**`$.load()`** É como se fosse o `require`/`include` do PHP, ele simplesmente irá adicionar o resultado do GET ao elemento, o use para dividir a aplicação em componentes e carrega-los assincronamente

Comment: Complementando, $ajax suporta diferente tipos de requisção como POST,PUT entre outras, e também te permite "personalizar melhor" sua resição, definindo  o  tipo  de dados que se espera receber, habiliando  e desabilitando  o async, permite cache quando  via GET, entre outras opições que os demais não  permite.

Answer (score 3):

[`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) é a função genérica para enviar uma requisição AJAX, todas as outras funções utilizam ela por de trás dos panos ([código](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/dfa92ccead70d7dd5735a36c6d0dd1af680271cd/src/ajax.js#L387));

A seguintes função foram criadas para facilitar a programação, mas todas elas chamam `$.ajax` (você pode verificar no link do código de cada uma delas).

- [`$.get(url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ])`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) ([código](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/dfa92ccead70d7dd5735a36c6d0dd1af680271cd/src/ajax.js#L834)). Equivalente a:

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
  });
  ```
- [`$.post(url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ])`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) ([código](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/dfa92ccead70d7dd5735a36c6d0dd1af680271cd/src/ajax.js#L834)). Equivalente a:

  ```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
  });
  ```
- [`$.getJSON(url [, data ] [, success ])`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) ([código](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/dfa92ccead70d7dd5735a36c6d0dd1af680271cd/src/ajax.js#L825)). Equivalente a:

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: "json"
  });
  ```
- [`$.getScript(url [, success ])`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) ([código](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/dfa92ccead70d7dd5735a36c6d0dd1af680271cd/src/ajax.js#L829)). Equivalente a:

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: success,
      dataType: "script"
  });
  ```

---

- [`$.fn.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) esta função se diferencia das anteriores, pois ela está vinculada a um objeto jQuery e tem uma função de *callback* pré definida, que é inserir o retorno do ajax como HTML do elemento.

Ela chama a função `$.ajax`, recebe um HTML e inclui o HTML recebido no elemento o qual esta função foi chamada([código](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/dfa92ccead70d7dd5735a36c6d0dd1af680271cd/src/ajax/load.js#L17)). Exemplo:

```
$('body').load('https://alguma.url.com/');
```

Tem o mesmo efeito que:

```
$.get('https://alguma.url.com/', function(data) {
    $('body').html(data);
})
```

Comment: Obrigada, me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Essa é a intenção! :D

Comment: Pena que o AP "não existe" mais, pq seria bom ele trocar a resposta correta por esta que está mais detalhada tecnicamente. Talvez o Costamilam também possa aproveitar e detalhar melhor a resposta dele (que está correta também)

Comment: É uma pena mesmo, mas se ficar com mais votos do que a aceita já serve como "dica" para os futuros visitantes. E obrigado pela edição, passou batido aqui. hahaha

Answer (score 1):

O `$.ajax` aceita, além de requisições GET, POST e PUT, diversas outras opções que o `$.get` e o `$.load` não possuem, por estes serem mais simplificados.

O `$.ajax` e o `$.get` possuem a mesma função, ou seja, fazer uma requisição HTTP, porém, como dito, o primeiro pode fazer GET, POST e PUT, enquanto o segundo somente GET. Logo, se você precisa, por exemplo, fazer um POST ou um PUT, o `$.get` já não será útil.

O `$.load` carrega o conteúdo de uma página em um elemento especificado no seletor:

```
$("#resultado").load("pagina.php");
```

Irá substituir o HTML do elemento `#resultado` (seletor) pelo conteúdo de `pagina.php`.

Mas também é possível usar o `$.load` passando informações via GET ou POST:

Via GET (informações passadas direto na URL):

```
$("#resultado").load("pagina.php?usuario=fulano");
```

Via POST (informações passadas via objeto `{}`):

```
$("#resultado").load("pagina.php", {usuario: "fulano"});
```

---

Determinar qual método usar vai depender muito da necessidade da sua aplicação. Deve também observar a versão do jQuery usado, porque algumas opções e callbacks se tornaram obsoletas e podem variar a partir de certas versões.

É bom dar uma olhada nas documentações:

- **[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**
- **[$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)**
- **[$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

Comment: Obrigada, me ajudou bastante.